# Snowflake -- find the number of rows for given table across all databases

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I have a table of the same name (`MY_TABLE` ) across multiple databases. Within a single database, I can find the number of rows using the following code:

```
select table_catalog, table_name, row_count
from information_schema.tables
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```

Is there a way to find the number of rows for `MY_TABLE` across all databases (or across a specified list)?

Edit: I currently do not have `ACCOUNT_USAGE` schema authorization.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES view

```
 select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, row_count
 from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES
 where table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```

N.B. Latency for the view may be up to 90 minutes

If you don't have access to the ACCOUNT_USAGE schema then an alternative is the "show" command e.g.

```
show tables like 'MY_TABLE' in account;
```

Comment: I am not authorized to see the `ACCOUNT_USAGE` schema, unfortunately (I'll try to get authorization). Do you know if there's a different way? Thanks.

Comment: information_schema.tables will show you all the tables that you have been granted access privileges to. If you want to see all tables, regardless of whether you have access privileges on them, the only way is to use the views in the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema

Comment: In `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, I can see all tables for a single database, but to see tables for a different database, I have to use `USE DATABASE MY_DATABASE` statement to switch. I am looking for a way to see all tables in a single view, so that I don't have to switch around numerous times.

Comment: Thank you, the second prompt `in account` worked exactly as desired!